# Getting EXIF data from images using ImageMagick inside AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, imagemagick, exif

I'm trying to extract EXIF data from images using ImageMagick inside AWS Lambda but I can't find the way to do it.

I have a piece of code to resize the image, it's working fine but I want to add the part to extract EXIF data.

Here is what I have right now to resize images:

```
var im = require("gm").subClass({imageMagick: true});
var operation = im(image.buffer).autoOrient().resize(width, height, '^');
operation.toBuffer(image.imageType, function(err, buffer) {
          if (err) {
            //do something with the error
          } else { 
             //do something with the image
          }
});
```

Any idea how to extract the metadata from the image ?

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: Did you try `gm("image.png").identify(callback)`? This is a getter that returns all image data available.

Comment: Yes, tried, does not works: "Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "identify" "-ping" "-verbose" "-" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found"

Comment: So, you’re looking for a native node package that doesn’t depend on gm/convert? Or have you tried to install the dependencies but not been successful?